# MPNowPlayingInfoCenter info doesn't work via USB accessory

Tags: objective-c, avplayer

I have an app that uses `AVPlayer` (actually `AVQueuePlayer`) for playing audio. It sets `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter` info, uses `MPRemoteCommandCenter` for managing remote commands, and allows background audio. All of this functionality works properly through control center and the lock screen. When I bring my phone into my car it also works properly with my car's bluetooth interface. However, if I plug my phone directly into my car's stereo via the iPhone 6 lightning port, it's broken badly. It actually does play the audio, but...

(1) None of the now playing info gets displayed on my car's dashboard
(2) My car's stereo throws up a bunch of connection errors whenever I try to do anything.

Other apps on my phone don't have this problem, so I don't think it's the fault of my stereo. I'm using official Apple lightning cables, so that's not related either.

I tried my app with AirPlay through my Apple TV and it was similarly wonky. I noticed that `AVPlayer` has an important property called `allowsExternalPlayback`, which needs to be set to `NO` if you're only playing audio. After setting that property to `NO`, AirPlay through the Apple TV works properly. I assumed this was the same problem that was effecting my car, but that does not appear to be the case. Even with `allowsExternalPlayback` set to `NO`, playing audio through the USB connection on my car is still screwed up.

It seems like it's something wrong with how either (a) the `AVAudioSession`, or (b) the `AVPlayer` is configured.

My audio player configuration is pretty simple...

```
self.audioQueue = [AVQueuePlayer queuePlayerWithItems:nil];
self.audioQueue.allowsExternalPlayback = NO;

[self.audioQueue addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:kAVPlayerStatusContext];
[self.audioQueue addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"rate" options:0 context:kAVPlayerRateContext];
[self.audioQueue addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"error" options:0 context:kAVPlayerErrorContext];
[self.audioQueue addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"currentItem" options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld | NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew) context:kAVPlayerCurrentItemContext];
```

... as in my audio session...

```
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

NSError *error;
[audioSession setActive:YES error:&error];
// Error handling code

[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&error];
// Error handling code

// Audio session notifications
NSNotificationCenter *defaultCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[defaultCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(audioSessionInterruptionNotification:) name:AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification object:audioSession];
[defaultCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(audioSessionRouteChangeNotification:) name:AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification object:audioSession];
[defaultCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(audioSessionMediaServicesWereResetNotification:) name:AVAudioSessionMediaServicesWereResetNotification object:audioSession];
```

Are there other properties that need to be set to handle this use case? What can I do to debug what's going on here? This one's got me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were 2 issues at play here...

1. I was setting `MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackQueueIndex` the same way I was setting `MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTrackCount`. After looking over the documentation, I realized that `MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackQueueIndex` is zero-based, and I was always setting queue index to 1 and queue count to 1. This was causing the car stereo to not display any information at all.
2. To play a track with `AVPlayer`, all you need to is set the rate to something other than 0. I noticed that I had an unnecessary call to `[audioQueue play]` right before I set the rate to my playback rate. I removed that unnecessary call to play, and it fixed my other problems. For some reason, that call had the effect of the car stereo immediately sending a play command after I pressed the pause button.